# Listbox rearranging string

Tags: vb.net, listbox

When I attempt to add a string to my list box:

```
    Do While sReader.Peek >= 0
        Dim line As String = (sReader.ReadLine)
        If line.Contains(":") Then
            line = line.Split(":")(1)
        End If
    For Each character As Char In line
            If Char.IsUpper(character) = True Then
                passToMask = passToMask & "?" & "u"
            ElseIf Char.IsLower(character) = True Then
                passToMask = passToMask & "?" & "l"
            ElseIf Char.IsNumber(character) = True Then
                passToMask = passToMask & "?" & "d"
            ElseIf Char.IsPunctuation(character) Then
                passToMask = passToMask & "?" & "s"
            ElseIf Char.IsSymbol(character) = True Then
                passToMask = passToMask & "?" & "s"
            ElseIf Char.IsWhiteSpace(character) = True Then
                passToMask = passToMask & "?" & "s"
            End If
        Next
        NewMask.Add(TextBox2.Text)
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text - 1
        Label3.Text = NewMask.Count()
        TextBox2.Text = ""
    Loop

    For Each mask In NewMask

        ListView1.Items.Add(mask)
    Next
```

It adds the string backwards d?d?
and what I want is ?d?d
Ive moved the passToMask = passToMask & "?" & "l" to passToMask = passToMask + "?l"
it just keeps switching the order. Listbox is unsorted also.

Comment: You may not be showing all the relevant code - that for loop is inside another loop and we cant see what happens before. You should also set `Option Strict On`.  Sample data which provides the undesired result would be nice too - the code should precede each code with a `?`

Comment: @Plutonix Added more of the code used. Also have tried listview and listbox

Comment: You never do anything with `passToMask` and it is not declared - is it a global variable?

Comment: No sorry it is a textbox

Comment: Huh?  If `passToMask` is a reference to a TextBox that code would not compile:  `passToMask = passToMask & "?" & "u"` is trying to concat text to a control reference.  Set `Option Strict On` always.

Comment: Option Strict Did it. I had to change a few things around and voila it works.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you just have to use `anyString.Reverse()` when it's a string.

Also you can control the behaviour of adding chars to string in that way you read the string.

Just use

```
// now you do "parse" your string backwards
for (int index = anyString.Length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
 char yourChar = anyString[index];
 // your logic here.
}
```

Comment: Negative .reverse has no effects on listbox or listview for me

Comment: I am not sure of how to use your suggestion, I will continue trying though.

Comment: You are using a foreach loop. Instead a foreach loop, you are using a for loop. WIth the giving index you are getting each loop, you are able to point to the char of your string, that has to be "masked". The kind of masking is in your for loop body (in my case, within my brackets). I would say, that you shouldn't tag your question as C#, when you are not able to "read" it. You removed it.. well. ^^

Comment: I included C# because more pros use it and it converts simple enough ----                                                                               
     For index As Integer = anyString.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
  ' your logic here.
 Dim yourChar As Char = anyString(index)
Next

Comment: That's the logic. And how exactly you cannot take this approach? You just replace your foreach loop with this logic. Then you are able to mask your chars backwards. That should correct your problem quite sure.